# Screen goes blank when I use NavLink

Tags: react-router-dom

I used NavLink in one of my js files it was working properly but suddenly when I used it In my other js component the page goes blank.

My App is wrapped by Router and as I said NavLink is working properly in one of my components which is the Login.js but if I use NavLink anywhere in the code and save it the browser gets blank and throws this error:

```
react-dom.development.js:18687 
    The above error occurred in the <NavLink> component:
    at NavLinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39346:21)
    at class
    at Signup
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40456:5)
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40389:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39198:5)
```

signup.js

````
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Signup() {
  return (
    <>
      <class className="full-container2">
        {/* <NavLink></NavLink> */}
        <section className="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <class className="left_data" style={{ width: "50%" }}>
            <class className="heading">
              <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            </class>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
                Name
              </label>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
                Email
              </label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputEmail1"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputPassword1"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
                Confirm Password
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputPassword1"
              />
            </div>
            <class className="createAcc">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-4">
                Create Account
              </button>
            </class>
          </class>
          <class className="right_data">
            <img src="./right NFT.png" alt="NFT Art" />
          </class>
        </section>
      </class>
    </>
  );
}```

Please Help me out with this
````

Comment: Is there any additional error output? It seems strange that it says `The above error occurred ` without showing any above error (though error messages sometimes are cryptic)

Comment: What is the ***actual*** error being reported? Can you provide a [mcve] where the `NavLink` component is actually used and rendered?